# Vaadin: recognize CSS classes added by HTML

Tags: java, css, sass, vaadin

In Vaadin, I am writing HTML into a RichTextArea, like this:

Java:

```
RichTextArea area = new RichTextArea();

StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
buf.append("<h1 class=\"previewPerson;\" style=\"text-align: right;\">" +
profile.getPersonName() + "</h1>\n");

//...

area.setValue(buf.toString());
```

SCSS (mystyle.scss):

```
.previewPerson {
color: $v-focus-color;
font: $v-font-family;
}
```

The "previewPerson" class shows up in styles.css as

```
.mystyle .previewPerson {
color: red;
font: Comic Sans;
}
```

...and the class shows up in my inspector, but does not have any effect. The inline styling does have an effect.

I want this style to be recognized in my .scss file if possible, as I would rather not write internal styling in my StringBuffer. I have tried `addStyleName("previewPerson")`, but was unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking another crack at `addStylename("previewPerson")`. What you need to do is add the style name of the component to the scss class.

So your Java would look like this:

```
RichTextArea area = new RichTextArea();
area.addStyleName("previewPerson");    
area.setValue(profile.getPersonName());
```

Your SCSS like this:

```
.v-richtextarea-previewPerson {
   text-align: right;
   color: $v-focus-color;
   font: $v-font-family;
}
```

Also, be careful with the RichTextArea,as you are potentially allowing cross-site scripting. Make sure your user inputs are [properly sanitized](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-security.html#advanced.security.sanitizing).

Comment: Thanks, and good call on avoiding the usage of the RichTextArea. I eventually found that I needed to use a templating engine to generate our displays, and I found that Vaadin had an interesting addon called [Freemarker Layout](https://github.com/alejandro-du/freemarker-layout) which suited my needs.